# Get more info from sqlclient error message

Tags: .net-cf-3.5, mysql

I connect my windows mobile app directly to ms-sql server using the sqlclient dll from microsoft.
Some times I get this error when trying to get some data from the server:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: SqlException
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning()
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
```

Every time I have a error like this I need to try a few other things, some times the connection string is no good, or the network is not configured right or any other random problem.

Is there a way I could get a bit more info from the program so I shouldn't have to waste a few hours figuring out what might went rung?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer... I changed: `Catch ex As Exception` To: `Catch ex As SqlException`

Now I get the specific error nicely displayed in the message.

Answer (score 0):

That's basically just the stack trace. You should be able to get the `Message` property of the `SqlException` which contains the details. In some cases you will have to look at the `InnerException` to get to the interesting details.

Comment: The InnerException is nothing.